# curl trying to connect to other port than mentioned in url

Tags: node.js, curl, port

im starting to build node app, and for this i am using curl. however, im facing an issue which i belive related to curl and my system configuration i just cant point  to the exact issue.

at my nodeJS app i set the app to listen on port 3000, andwhenever i type in the command line :

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"url":"localhost:3000"}'  http://localhost:3000/doAction
```

im getting the following error :

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused
```

it seems like curl is forcing connection to port 1080, although i was specifing port 3000, couldt find solution for this in the documentation.
if someone met this issue before and can assist it will be graet. tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your curl is trying to connect to proxy  (default port 1080),  why don't you run the command with --noproxy '*' i.e

curl --noproxy '*' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"url":"localhost:3000"}'  http://localhost:3000/doAction

Comment: it might be it but --noproxy isnt working and still same result

Comment: I'm having similar problem when curl localhost, what can cause " trying to connect to proxy (default port 1080)"?